# Errors while importing an android application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I have a android application which is working fine in a system. I copied the project from that system and trying to install it on different system. The same project is working fine on that system but it doesn't build on new system. There is no change in coding and all the sdks are installed. The style sheet file has following error for a style:

> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 
>    'android:overScrollMode'.

In other files I am getting import R can not be resolved error.

I have selected Google API 2.2 from Android build target. The minSdkVersion is set as 8 in AndroidMaifest.xml Is there anything else that I need to change in my project settings?

Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

`overScrollMode` was added with API 9. Change your `minSdkVersion` and you will fix the problem.

The errors regarding `R` are caused by the error in your XML files.

Comment: but it works on other system with same configurations

Comment: @Pankaj Then you need to remove the `overScrollMode`